# Is there any free software to open and edit .so files?

Tags: disassembly

I am not thinking of a specific platform, anyway I likes to read and edit .so files

Comment: Do you mean dynamic libraries on *nix platforms and what do you mean by edit?

Comment: Have you considered libbfd/binutils? It ought to have most of the functionality anyone could want for manipulating .so files. It would be helpful if you would clarify your question a little.

Comment: Try a compiler / linker

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choice:

- IDA Pro(Commercial, expensive): can disassemble .so files (linux lib)
- objdump(Free and opensource): it is part of binutils package.
- ODA(Free): an oline disassembler (www.onlinedisassembler.com)
- Hopper(Commercial, cheap):  can disassemble .so files

So, if you are looking for something free, objdump or ODA are your best bets.

Remember that the platform matter! For example if you are trying to diassemble a .so file from an ARM Android system with objdump, you need to install objdump from the ARM gcc toolchain.

Comment: `objdump` is part of `binutils`, not part of the GCC toolchain. The GCC toolchain merely depends on `binutils`. Usual distros offer `binutils` for other architectures.

Comment: Thank you very much @C0000022L for pointing this out, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

From http://file.org/extension/so

Winrar and Media Player are supposed to be able to open them.  You can also try a universal file opener: 
http://file.org/free-download/free-file-viewer